# Chrome autofill username field but not the password field

Tags: html, google-chrome

I want to stop the auto-filling of the password field on the login form for the website I am working on. I still want the username field to be auto-filled by Chrome. Currently I have put the `autocomplete="new-password"` attribute on the password input field only.

This seems to have turned Chrome's autofill functionality off for both the username input field as well as the password input field.

Is there a way to specify Chrome's autofill functionality per input field, or is it all or nothing?